# removing unclosed img tag

Tags: php, html

how to remove the img tag that is not complete (unclosed img tag) in a string?.

example:

```
$text = 'blllaa <img src="my-image.png"/> Blaa Blaa Blaa <img src ="my-image2.png';
```

then I want the second img tag is removed because it's not complete. And the output will be like this:

```
$output = 'blllaa<img src="my-image.png"/>Blaa Blaa Blaa';
```

As always any help is appreciated and thanks in advance. And sorry for my bad english -.-

Comment: If the string is exactly like that, it should be trivial. If you're asking how to validate HTML with PHP, it's not trivial at all.

Comment: how do you actually construct $text? posting more of your actual code is probably beneficial

Answer (score 5):

You can use Tidy (http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.repairstring.php ).Tidy repairs a string and unclosed tags..